# Unable to clear the custom component children

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to clear all the texts in the child custom components when the reset button is clicked in the parent. I have tried everything but I still can't get it to work. I'm pretty new with react native. Should I just directly use TextInput component in the MultipleFoo component instead to make it less convoluted?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Foo = ({ onChangeText, id, isClearText }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          borderRadius: 8,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          padding: 5,
          height: 50,
          marginBottom: 10,
          marginHorizontal: 20,
        }}
        onChangeText={(inputText) => {
          isClearText? setText('') : setText(inputText);
          onChangeText(id, inputText);
          
        }}
        value={text}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const MultipleFoo = ({ onDataChanged, onReset }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    foo1: '',
    foo2: '',
    foo3: '',
  });

  const handleDataChange = (id, newData) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      const updatedData = { ...prevData, [id]: newData };
      onDataChanged(updatedData);
      return updatedData;
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Foo id="foo1" onChangeText={handleDataChange} isClearText={onReset}/>
      <Foo id="foo2" onChangeText={handleDataChange} isClearText={onReset}/>
      <Foo id="foo3" onChangeText={handleDataChange} isClearText={onReset}/>
    </View>
  );
};

interface ButtonProps {
  text: string;
  handlePress: () => void;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ text, handlePress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={handlePress}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState({});
  const [data2, setData2] = useState({});
  const [isReset, setIsReset] = useState(false);

  const handleDataChange1 = (newData) => {
    setData1(newData);
    console.log(data1);
  };

  const handleDataChange2 = (newData) => {
    setData2(newData);
    console.log(data2);
  };

  const clearText = () => {
    console.log('clear text')
    
    setData1({
      foo1: '',
      foo2: '',
      foo3: '',
    });
    setData2({
      foo1: '',
      foo2: '',
      foo3: '',
    });
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data2);
    setIsReset(true);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Item 1</Text>
      <MultipleFoo onDataChanged={handleDataChange1} onReset={isReset} />
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Item 2</Text>
      <MultipleFoo onDataChanged={handleDataChange2} onReset={isReset} />
      <Button text={'Reset'} handlePress={clearText} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: You are defining a new state at every level. Pass the state from App level to children. See https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components for details.